# Using forEach with an array to find a string and return a function

Tags: arrays, angularjs, for-loop

I'm trying to create a discount code system of sorts using AngularJS. I have a resultant function $scope.pricetotal that defines a certain value. I have an input defined that registers a string. I also have an array defined. Here's what I'm trying to do: I'm trying to match the input string with the array and if there is a match, I'm trying to return a total based on a value associated with the matched string in the array. But I seem to be missing something. First, here is my aray:

```
var array = {
    "results": [{
      "amt": 5,
      "name": "12345",
      "percent": 0
    }, {
      "amt": 0,
      "name": "23456",
      "percent": 5
    }]
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
            <label>Discount Code:</label>
            <span style="float:right;">
                <input ng-model="disc" size="10" type="text"><md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="$log.log(disc)">
      Enter
    </md-button>
<h3>TOTAL = {{ discprice | currency }}</h3>
</div>
```

Here's my js:

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
var app = angular.module('app', []);
//$scope.pricetotal has been defined in another .factory and I can confirm it generates a correct numerical value. I just didn't include it to make things simpler. THe factory is also defined as a function in the controller below.
app.controller('MyController', function($scope, $log) {
$scope.$log = $log;
$scope.disc = 'Enter Code';
var output = function() {
        var discountedprice = '';
        angular.forEach($scope.discount, function(item) {
          var discountname = item.name;
          if (discountname.indexOf($scope.disc) > -1) {
          discountedprice = ((100 - parseInt(item.percent))/100 * parseInt($scope.pricetotal)) -  parseInt(item.amt);
          }
          discountedprice = $scope.pricetotal;
        });
        return discountedprice;
      };
      $scope.discprice = output();
    });
})(window.angular);
```

The only output I'm getting for the total is $0.00, not sure why. I checked my console and I do see the input being stored, so that part works; so I'm assuming the latter part of my code has a syntax error and I would appreciate anyone's help with this. Basically, If the input string matches with the array, I need the function ((100-x)/100*$scope.pricetotal)-y, where x and y are associated with the matched string in the array. If there is no match, I wish to return $scope.pricetotal itself, which is the original value I'm playing with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$scope.discprice = output();`

Looks like this is only getting called once and that is when the controller is initialised.

You could do `$scope.discprice = output`  (without executing the function) and in the html, bind to `<h3>TOTAL = {{ discprice() || currency }}</h3>`

Or when you click the button, call `$scope.discprice()`, which would then calculate and set the price on a scope variable which you can bind to from the html

Comment: Thanks for your response. I switched to $scope.discprice = output and used <h3>TOTAL = {{ discprice() || currency }}</h3> as you have kindly suggested, however, I now get several errors: TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined. Any ideas of what might be causing the same?

Comment: Would you be able to quickly whip up a plunker for this problem?

Comment: Yes, sir. I'll post the same in a bit.

Comment: I whipped up a plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/bLqAdpGOwMsNThK3Ei6s?p=preview Sorry for the delay. For reference purposes, a more complete code I'm working on is here: http://plnkr.co/edit/4ByCDzXZfRU7kMX9oURT?p=preview - If you add an item in the menu tab, the html is present in the order tab and the relevant script is in the controller 'EmailController'.

Comment: You had $scope.discount wrapped in an object and was trying to loop through it. But instead, it should be an array. That fixes the TypeError

http://plnkr.co/edit/MnNMLJZiu0P8yEzmBkpj?p=preview

Comment: Thanks! That fixed the TypeError now, which is a step in the right direction. But the code still doesn't work. When I input '12345' and press Enter, it doesn't change the value. Any ideas with that? Thanks a bunch again.

Comment: Sorry, just had a really quick question. Now that I have an output discprice() in that plunker, how do I call that in the controller to do more things with it, like send it through an email? If I call $scope.discprice() in the controller, I only get an undefined value. Thanks again!